# how to insert more than one values in one object by calling setter method in HAS-A relationship in java

Tags: java

```
class Address {
    private int pincode;
    private String village;
    //setters  to store multiple values
}

class Student{
    private int sid;
    private String
    // setter methods for inserting values into student object
    Address a=new Address();//HAS-A relationship
    a.setPincode(1111);
    a.setVillage("xxxxxx");// temporary address
    a.setPincode(2547);
    a.setVillage("yyyyy"); permanent address
    // so here i want to  inject more than one address parameters to Student object
    // like i want to print temporary adress and permament address for one student object
    System.out.println(studentobject);
    // toString method overriden
}
```

For example if I print `studentobject`, I want output both temporary address and permanent address.. for one student object.

Comment: Have a List of Address

Comment: I'm not even sure if that code will compile?

Comment: code will not execute,bcs i dididnt write total code ..i explain the scenario.we can able to print studentobject(both temporaryaddress and permanent adress) as above explained .with out using collections and arrays@christopher

Comment: Best Option:
class Student
{
Address temporarayAddress = new Address();
Address permanentAddress = new Address();
}

If you want only in a single object, have a List<Address> addresses, but I dont think,Array is a correct solution for storing just two addresses

Comment: remove this line  System.out.println(studentobject);, you can't make in a method call in  a class. You can make method calls in only a method definition.

Answer (score 0):

The way you designed it, one object of type `Address` can hold exactly one pincode and one village name. After creating your object, you store two values (1111 and "xxxxxx") and in the two lines after that, you just overwrite them. The previous data is not available anymore.

The best way to design this would probably be to put two class fields into your `Student` class. Then you can set two addresses (in one setter or have two separate setters). And in the `toString()` you print both addresses.

```
class Student{
    private int sid;
    private String name;
    private Address tempAddress;
    private Address permAddress;

    public void setAddress(Address tempAddress, Address permAddress) {
        this.tempAddress = tempAddress;
        this.permAddress = permAddress;
    }

    //Other methods here...

    public String toString() {
        //Concatenate your addresses somehow, you might need to implement toString for Address
        String addresses = tempAddress + "\n" + permAddress; 
        return addresses;
    }   
}
```

Comment: thank you for explanation. one object(Address) cannot hold 2 objects??

Comment: Exactly, one `Address` object can only hold values of one "physical" address.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Address {
private int tempAddressPincode;
private String tempAddressVillage;
//storing tempAddress with above two variables
private int permAddressPincode;
private String permAddressVillage;
//storing permAddress with above two variables
}
```

This can be one solution to you requirement.

One more solution, you can go for is taking an array

```
Address[] addresses = new Address[2].

addresses[0] for tempAddress and addresses[1] for permanent address.
```

Comment: That would work, but the class name `Address` (singular) is somewhat misleading...

Comment: Yeah, might be. Then, we can name it as AddressInfo which gives the info of both temporary address and permanent address.